# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.io.InputStream

Tags: java, php, string, casting, base64

I'm writing a php script which is interfacing with a SOAP client (which is internally using java).

One of the calls requires that I pass Base64 encoded content.

I'm passing it like this:

```
(Edit 1)
$content=file_get_contents('fileX'); 
fileX is a binary file which has been uploaded via POST and saved successfully in /tmp.
It is ~600kb in binary form.

$args[]=array('name'=>'content', 'value'=>base64_encode($content), 'type'=>'Base64Binary');
```

But, I'm getting an error:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.io.InputStream


(Edit2)
The documentation of the third party application says exactly:
Parameter   Description                               Type
filename    The name of the presentation file         String
            including the file extension. 
content     The content of the presentation file      Base64Binary
            encoded in Base64 scheme.
```

Comment: What is the type of `$content`?

Comment: @evan - please see edit1

Comment: It seems like the Java code, not your PHP, is the problem. Java may be expecting a Stream instead of a string. Could you post the piece of Java that is parsing this array?

Comment: @evan - hi evan - actually, that's a stable third party application (which i dont have access to the source of). I'm doing something wrong, but i need help in understanding where its breaking.

Comment: (i need to alter what i'm doing in order to get it to work)

Comment: Have you tried [chunk splitting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php)? Like `'value'=> chunk_split(base64_encode($content))`

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in the array is of type String, due to the output type of `base64_decode`. That Java error implies that it is expecting an object of type InputStream.

You may need to use the Zend PHP Java Bridge as seen here:

https://fosswiki.liip.ch/display/~chregu/Convert+PHP+String+to+a+Java+InputStream

in order to convert that String to a Java InputStream.

Download Zend Server here:

http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/downloads

or an alternative PHP Java Bridge here:

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/installation.php

Comment: Hi @evan - are you sure? I would hate to install/setup any of this just for one piece of functionality. Is there a better way? (See edit 2 as well please)

Comment: You could try passing the value from `fopen()`, and see if Java recognizes the format. I'm not sure if this will work.